# Why wont my for loop run while inside a tkinter instance

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am trying to take input from a user and use that input to generate random passwords but I do not know why the for loop is not running. Does code run before or after root.mainloop() and if it runs before why is my for loop not running?

```
   from tkinter import *
import random
password_len = 0
password_count = 0
chars = """"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\"':;<,>.?/"""

def retrieve():
    global password_len
    global password_count
    password_len = int(my_entry.get())
    password_count = int(my_entry2.get())
    
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
 
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)
 
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "Generated Passwords")
        self.label.pack()
 
        self.text = Text(self.frame, undo = True, height = 20, width = 70)
        self.text.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH) 
        
root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

var = StringVar()
var.set("Please enter the length you want your password(s) to be and how many passwords you would like")

label = Label(frame, textvariable = var )
label.pack()

my_entry = Entry(frame, width = 20)
my_entry.insert(0, 'Length')
my_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

my_entry2 = Entry(frame, width = 20)
my_entry2.insert(0, 'How many')
my_entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

Button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = retrieve)
Button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

for i in range(0, password_count):
    self.text.insert(i, "Password: ")
    password = ""
    for i in range(0,password_len):
        password_char = random.choice(chars)
        password += password_char
    self.text.insert(i + password)

window = Window(root)
root.title("Password Generator")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: because `password_count = 0` so the range is non-existent

Answer (score 1):

- Removed all global. Because you are working on creating an
  instantiated class.
- Put widget Button inside `__init__`. And renamed `self.button`
  instead of `Button=`. Add `self.retrieve` in `command`
- Put the `retrieve()` function inside `__init__`. And add `self` in
  parameter.
- Removed looping and this in the `retrieve()` function.
- Used **f-string** and added `'\n\'` newline in text

Here is a code and to improve readability:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


chars = """"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\"':;<,>.?/"""
   
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
 
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)
 
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text = "Generated Passwords")
        self.label.pack()
 
        self.text = Text(self.frame, undo = True, height = 20, width = 70)
        self.text.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)

        self.button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = self.retrieve)
        self.button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


    def retrieve(self):
        password_len = int(my_entry.get())
        password_count = int(my_entry2.get())
        
        for i in range(0, password_count):
            password = ""
            for i in range(0,password_len):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
        self.text.insert( 'end', f'{i}  {password}\n')
                     
            
root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

var = StringVar()
var.set("Please enter the length you want your password(s) to be and how many passwords you would like")

label = Label(frame, textvariable = var )
label.pack()

my_entry = Entry(frame, width = 20)
my_entry.insert(0, 'Length')
my_entry.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

my_entry2 = Entry(frame, width = 20)
my_entry2.insert(0, 'How many')
my_entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

 
window = Window(root)
root.title("Password Generator")
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]